# Need a procedure to update null columns from master table if not remarks column should be Unmatched

Tags: plsql, sqlplus

For example

Table 1: `deparmant_master`. Columns :
`Department_id, deparment name`

Table 2: `Cadre_master`.     Columns :
`Cadre_id, cadre_name, Department_id`

Table 3: `Post_master`. Columns :
`Post_id, Post_name, Cadre_id, Department_id`

Table 4: `Temp`. Columns :
`Department_name,Department_id,Post_id, Cadre_id, Cadre_name, Remarks`

I need to write a procedure to update `temp` table if `dept_id` is null and `department` name is not null then update `department_id` from `department_master`, Like the same cadre is null and post id is null in `temp` table respecting to master I need to update the column `accordingly`.
If not matched records I need to update `REMARKS` column has unmatched/False.

Comment: "Like same cadre and post id is null respecting to master i need to update" - this part does not make sense to me.

Comment: It would make it a lot more easier if you provided all of the following: the create table scripts, some sample data, the expected output, what you already tried and where you got stuck. Remember Stack Overflow is NOT a homework writing service.

Comment: If Master has data and temp data is null like Cadre_id or post id is null based on the master the null values of temp data should be updated.

Comment: @RahulTR - please edit your question to show your work. Also, any clarifications to your questions should be put in the question itself as well. Currently, your question only contains your requirement (maybe a classroom assignment?), and you haven't included any details around what you've done, where you're stuck, errors, output issues, etc.